# Flutter Doctor - Android studion not recognized

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I've just installed Fresh Linux Mint 18.3 on an 960evo ssd and Im having some problem with flutter doctor. Namely when I run flutter doctor it says that I don;t have installed Android Studio but in fact it's already installed on my system. I can run flutter app in Intelij using emulator device but doctor is complaining.

```
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.3.2, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 0.3.2 at /home/mugen/development/flutter
    • Framework revision 44b7e7d3f4 (5 weeks ago), 2018-04-20 01:02:44 -0700
    • Engine revision 09d05a3891
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.48.0.flutter-fe606f890b

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/mugen/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
    • Java binary at: /usr/bin/java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✗] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.io/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.1)
    • IntelliJ at /home/mugen/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/181.5087.20
    • Flutter plugin version 24.2.2
    • Dart plugin version 181.4892.1

[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: Which version of android studio you are using? You must be using android studio 3.0 or higher to install the flutter plugins

Comment: @NaveenTP `.AndroidStudio3.1/` also I've installed flutter plugin in the AS

Answer (score 0):

flutter is supported by android studio 3.0 and above version

please update your android studio version

Android Studio 3.0 is out now, to get it you have to click on Help>Check for Updates. Once it finishes checking for updates, a window will appear with the Download option